# Timeout while deploying nodejs based chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am getting the below error while trying to deploy any nodejs based chaincode on hyperledger 1.4 network :

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg timeout expired while starting
>   chaincode

I have even tried the base example chaincode_example02, that is also giving the same error.

Please help.

Comment: there can be multiple reasons for that, are you behind a proxy? this is the most prominent reason as chaincode is not able to download the dependencies.

Comment: No I am not behind a proxy, also go-lang version chaincode is working fine.